# I can not understand why it is giving array out of bound exception for the quicksort program?

Tags: java, quicksort

My code seems to be fine but why it is giving array out of bounds exception

```
    import java.util.*;  
    import java.io.*;  
    class Qsort  
    {  
        static int partition(int a[],int l,int h)  
        {   
            int pivot=l;  
            int u=h;  
            while(l<=h)  
            {
                while(a[pivot]>=a[l] && l<=u )  
                    l++;  
                while(a[pivot]<a[h])  
                    h--;  
                if(l<=h)  
                {   
                    int temp=a[l];  
                    a[l]=a[h];  
                    a[h]=a[l];      
                }  
            }  
            int t=a[pivot];  
            a[pivot]=a[h];  
            a[h]=t;  
            return h;     
        }  
        static void qs(int a[],int l,int h)  
        {  
            if(l<h)  
            {  
                int v=partition(a,l,h);  
                qs(a,l,v-1);  
                qs(a,v+1,h);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    class Qsmain  
    {  
        public static void main (String ars[]) throws IOException  
        {  
            int a[]= {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5};  
            int n=6;  
            Qsort.qs(a,0,n-1);  
            System.out.println("The Sorted array is - ");  
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  
                System.out.print(a[i]+" ");   
        }  
    }
```

the exception as shown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6  
        at Qsort.partition(Qsmain.java:16)  
        at Qsort.qs(Qsmain.java:36)  
        at Qsmain.main(Qsmain.java:61)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is coming from this line:

```
    while(a[pivot]>=a[l] && l<=u )
        l++;
```

When you are looping through, at some stage `l = 5` and `u = 5`, so `l++ = 6`, which then throws Exception as `a[6]` is out of bounds (last member is `a[5]`). So to fix this, change statement to:

```
    while(a[pivot]>=a[l] && l<u ) //instead of l<=u, write l<u
```

But this will cause the next error, because             `while(l<=h)` will translate into `while(5<=5)` and will then run forever, as the last value of `l` is 5 and it will not get incremented. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be a variation of Hoare Partition scheme. Below is a simple example of basic Hoare Partition scheme. The scans from either end don't need to check for going out of range, since left scan will always run into a value >= pivot and right scan will always run into a value <= pivot. During a partition step, elements equal to the pivot or the pivot itself can end up anywhere in the partitions, and the index *hh* is just a boundary between left partition (elements <= pivot) and right partition (elements >= pivot), so the element at a[hh] needs to be included in one of the recursive calls (in this example, it's the first recursive call).

```
    public static void qsort(int[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if(lo < hi){
            int ll = lo-1;
            int hh = hi+1;
            int p = a[lo+(hi-lo)/2];
            int t;
            while(true){
                while(a[++ll] < p);
                while(a[--hh] > p);
                if(ll >= hh)
                    break;
                t     = a[ll];
                a[ll] = a[hh];
                a[hh] = t;
            }
            ll = hh++;
            qsort(a, lo, ll);
            qsort(a, hh, hi);
        }
    }
```